# PhpStorm : Generate a database Initialization script

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

When I do either these actions :

- Right click on the schema / copy DDL
- Compare 2 datasources / untick ignore order / click migrate left

The generated CREATE TABLE statements are alphabetically ordered.

Since there are foreign keys, I obviously get a useless script as I want to run it on an empty schema.

Is there a solution using PhpStorm or I have to use mysqldump ?

Comment: `mysqldump` will create consistent dumps, and more importantly, the `--single-transaction` option helps snapshot live datasets.

Comment: You may also call mysqldump right from PhpStorm (via context menu on your datasource) .. but I do not think that you can provide `--no-data` parameter to only have structure and not the whole dump. So yeah -- mysqldump is the better way to go right now. Consider filing a Feature Request ticket if it does not exist yet (my quick search showed no obvious matches) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE (post a link back in case you do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LazyOne suggested I can't do that in phpstorm.
That would be a nice feature indeed. I can't easily report the feature request...

I therefore used a mysqldump extract.